# MySQLi $userid returning 0

Tags: php, mysqli

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
    $time = time();

if($password != $confirmpassword) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?error=1" />';
    die();
} else {
        if($username != '') {
            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?error=2" />';
            die();
        } else {


    $checkemail = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `email` = ?");
    $checkemail->bind_param('s', $email);
    $checkemail->execute();
    $checkemail->store_result(); 
    $emailrows = $checkemail->num_rows;
    $checkemail->free_result();

    if($emailrows > '0') {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?error=3" />';
    die();

    } else {

    $checkdisplay = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `display` = ?");
    $checkdisplay->bind_param('s', $name);
    $checkdisplay->execute();
    $checkdisplay->store_result(); 
    $displayrows = $checkdisplay->num_rows;
    $checkdisplay->free_result();

    if($displayrows > '0') {
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?error=4" />';
    die();

    } else {

    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?error=5" />';
        die();
    } else {

    $createaccount = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `member` (`display`, `email`, `salt`, `password`, `rank`, `joined`, `ip`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $salt = sha1(rand(10000000, 99999999));
    $encrypt = sha1($password . $salt);
    $rank = '1';
    $createaccount->bind_param('ssssiis', $name, $email, $salt, $encrypt, $rank, $time, $ip);
    $createaccount->execute();

    $getid = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `member` WHERE `display` = ?");
    $getid->bind_param('s', $name);
    $getid->execute();
    $getid->bind_result($userid);
    $getid->free_result();

    if(!$userid) {
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?error=6" />';
        die();
    } else {
            $encryptip = sha1($ip);


                session_regenerate_id();

                $_SESSION['sesid'] = $userid;
                $_SESSION['sesip'] = $encryptip;

                session_write_close();
ob_get_clean();
echo 'success';
echo $userid;
echo $encryptip;
    }

    }
    }

    }

}
}
```

I'm just learning the ropes of MySQLi, so got this mostly from a tutorial (though had to throw in parts from different sites - hence the errors).

Is anyone able to explain why $userid returns `0` instead of `1` that it should be? I'm hoping it's a simple mistake.

The query is correct, I've looked over it multiple times, and yes, `$name` is set.

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($userid);` on the line after your `bind_result()` call?

Comment: asking someone to find an error in the code for you is offtopic. I told you what have to be done already: you leave only code that fetches userid and then verify all the input and output and premises. For some reason you stuck to your long and windy code and verified NOTHING.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I'm asking because I'm totally lost, I have no idea how MySQLi works and I'm hoping someone can help me.

Comment: @Alex.Ritna It outputs int(0). It's not setting for some reason.

Comment: @TedMosby Have you executed the MySQL query using the same data as is contained in $name, at the mysql prompt or another mysql client to verify the result of the query?

Comment: it is not about mysqli. it is about what you have to do. You have been told what to do, but refused to do so.

Comment: @Alex.Ritna Yes, when executed directly in PhpMyAdmin it gets the correct results.

Comment: @TedMosby I now see what YourCommonSense was talking about. You should heed the advice you've received as answers in your other mysqli related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you don't need to select user id this way. As you just inserted data in the table, then you have call insert_id() function to get autogenerated id. That's all.

As of such "problems" in general - again: you have to **isolate** that code snippet, **add code to verify every single one premise** (var_dumping input, selecting raw DB content without conditions, comparing data from db with input (I mean **code** that compares and outputs the result)) and - if still unable to solve - be able to post both code along with **output** in your question, to make it sane and answerable.

You have to understand that **code doesn't exist in vacuum**. It runs on the *server* with it's distinct *environment*, it uses a *database*, it processes some *input* - **ALL THESE THINGS TOTALLY UNKNOWN FOR THE READER** - and thus it makes a question that consists of only code totally useless.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will look into insert_id(). Thanks for the additional information too.

Comment: I'll edit the question as well to make it a bit more broad so that it can be kept with your answer.